# How to make a deductive logic game of guessing a three degit number?

Tags: python, dictionary, random, input, zip

The question is: In Bagels, a deductive logic game, you must guess a secret three-digit number based on clues. The game offers one of the following hints in response to your guess: “Pico” when your guess has a correct digit in the wrong place, “Fermi” when your guess has a correct digit in the correct place, and “Bagels” if your guess has no correct digits. You have 10 tries to guess the secret number.

I am new in Python. Any suggestions are appreciated:

```
#Generating a random 3-digit number
import random
from random import randint

def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)
    
random_number=random_with_N_digits(3)
print(random_number)

#Making a dictionary From the integers of the number
#Indexes as Keys and integers as values
rand_list = [int(x) for x in str(random_number)]
rand_dictionary=dict(zip(range(len(rand_list)),rand_list))
#rand_dictionary

#For loop for 10 tries
for i in range(10):
    input_num = int(input('Please guess that three digit number : '))
    #Validating the input
    if input_num < 999 and input_num > 100:
        #Making dictionary for the inputted number in similar way like the random number
        input_list = [int(x) for x in str(input_num)]
        input_dictionary = dict(zip(range(len(input_list)), input_list))
        if random_number == input_num:
            print("Your answer is correct!!")
            break
        elif [i for (i, j) in zip(rand_list, input_list) if i == j]:
            print("Fermi")
            if set(rand_list) & set(input_list):
                print("Pico")
        elif set(rand_list) & set(input_list):
            print("Pico")
        else:
            print("Bagels")
    else:
        print("This is not a valid three digit number. Please try again.")
print("The test is finished.")
```

Comment: What is your question? If the code works and you just want feedback on it, try asking at [codereview.se].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got what you wanted but try this:

```
#Generating a random 3-digit number
import random
from random import randint

def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)
    
random_number=random_with_N_digits(3)
print(random_number)

#Making a dictionary From the integers of the number
#Indexes as Keys and integers as values
rand_list = [int(x) for x in str(random_number)]
rand_dictionary=dict(zip(range(len(rand_list)),rand_list))
#rand_dictionary

#For loop for 10 tries
i = 0
while i < 10:
    try:
        input_num = int(input('Please guess that three digit number : '))
        #Validating the input
        if input_num < 999 and input_num > 100:
            #Making dictionary for the inputted number in similar way like the random number
            input_list = [int(x) for x in str(input_num)]
            print(input_list)
            input_dictionary = dict(zip(range(len(input_list)), input_list))
            if input_num == random_number:
                print("Your answer is correct!!")
                break
            elif set(rand_list) & set(input_list):
                correct_place = 0
                for j in range(0, len(input_list)):
                    if rand_list[j] == input_list[j]:
                        correct_place += 1
                correct_digits = len(set(rand_list) & set(input_list))
                print("Fermi "*correct_place + "Pico "*(correct_digits - correct_place))
            else:
                print("Bagels")
            i += 1
        else:
            print("This is not a valid three digit number. Please try again.")
    except:
        print("Not a valid input")

print("The test is finished.")
```

Comment: Your code is improved. One thing that I noticed is that, if there is multiple occurrences of same hint, your code correctly mentions that hint exactly the same number of times, as it occurred. Which was absent in my code. Thank you for reviewing my code.